# help: Stability analysis (CFL condition, ...) for unsteady Navier Stokes

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am using mixed finite element method (with Taylor-Hood elements) to solve unsteady Navier Stokes. Can someone help me on stability analysis of the first order *Euler method, to find the restriction on dt step size?

*I am using implicit scheme for the viscous part and explicit for the convection part.

Comment: Could you write down your model and the discretization?